# How to predict probability in logistic regression in SAS?

Tags: sas, probability, prediction, logistic-regression

I am very new to SAS and trying to predict probabilities using logistic regression in SAS. I got the code below from SAS Support web site:

```
  data vaso;
  length Response $12;
  input Volume Rate Response @@;
  LogVolume=log(Volume);
  LogRate=log(Rate);
  datalines;
3.70  0.825  constrict       3.50  1.09   constrict
1.25  2.50   constrict       0.75  1.50   constrict
0.80  3.20   constrict       0.70  3.50   constrict
0.60  0.75   no_constrict    1.10  1.70   no_constrict
0.90  0.75   no_constrict    0.90  0.45   no_constrict
0.80  0.57   no_constrict    0.55  2.75   no_constrict
0.60  3.00   no_constrict    1.40  2.33   constrict
0.75  3.75   constrict       2.30  1.64   constrict
3.20  1.60   constrict       0.85  1.415  constrict
1.70  1.06   no_constrict    1.80  1.80   constrict
0.40  2.00   no_constrict    0.95  1.36   no_constrict
1.35  1.35   no_constrict    1.50  1.36   no_constrict
1.60  1.78   constrict       0.60  1.50   no_constrict
1.80  1.50   constrict       0.95  1.90   no_constrict
1.90  0.95   constrict       1.60  0.40   no_constrict
2.70  0.75   constrict       2.35  0.03   no_constrict
1.10  1.83   no_constrict    1.10  2.20   constrict
1.20  2.00   constrict       0.80  3.33   constrict
0.95  1.90   no_constrict    0.75  1.90   no_constrict
1.30  1.625  constrict
;
ods graphics on;

proc logistic data=vaso PLOTS = (ROC EFFECT);
  model Response(event='constrict')=LogRate LogVolume 
  /ctable pprob=0.5 selection=forward rsquare link=logit expb ;
run;
ods graphics off;
```

I am wondering how I could predict the probability when I have `logVolume= 1.5` and `logRate=1.3`. Also, can you please explain what `length Response $12` above means?

Comment: The `length` statement is defining how long the character variable `Response` may be (how many characters long a response may be), and defining it at 12 bytes (12 characters).

For the rest of your question I'm not sure that's a programming question.  You certainly can't run a regression from one data point.  If you're asking how to interpret the results of the logistic regression, I'd ask that on [stats.se] as it's not really a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping to calculate the probability in SAS, not by hand. That's why I asked it here

Comment: Sure, but what do you mean `calculate the probability`?  Are you meaning you want to obtain the values for the various regression parameters and predict a new value based on those?  That's certainly possible, but honestly if you don't know what `length` means you probably need to learn basic SAS before you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 ways to get predicted values:
1. Using Score method in proc logistic
2. Adding the data to the original data set, minus the response variable and getting the prediction in the output dataset.

Both are illustrated in the code below:

```
*Create an dataset with the values you want predictions for;
data pred_wanted;
input logvolume lograte;
cards;
1.5 1.3
;
run;

*append to predicted data set;
data vaso2;
set vaso pred_wanted;
run;

*run model with new options;
proc logistic data=vaso2 ;
  model Response(event='constrict')=LogRate LogVolume 
  /ctable pprob=0.5 selection=forward rsquare link=logit expb ;
  *Get output from vaso2 (method2);
  output out=estimates p=est_response;
  *Get output from pred_wanted(method1);
  score data=pred_wanted out=estimates2;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

As another option, the [`code` statement in `proc logistic`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_syntax08.htm) will save SAS code to a file to calculate the predicted probability from the regression parameters that you estimated.  In this example, it would look something like this:

```
proc logistic data=vaso PLOTS = (ROC EFFECT);
 model Response(event='constrict')=LogRate LogVolume 
 /ctable pprob=0.5 selection=forward rsquare link=logit expb ;
 CODE "pprob.sas";
run;

data probabilities;
 input logVolume logRate;
 %include "pprob.sas";
 cards;
 1.5 1.3
 ;
run;
```

The data set probabilities should contain the predicted values from the fitted model.

Comment: Yes, it's in SAS help [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_syntax08.htm).  It may be new to SAS 9.4; I hadn't seen it before when I went looking for ways to do this.