# use estimates from proc glm to make prediciton on another dataset

Tags: sas

I'm not so familiar with SAS `proc glm`. All I have done using `proc glm` so far is to output parameter estimates and predicted values on training datasets. But I also need to use the fitted model to make prediction on testing dataset. (both point estimates and interval estimates)

Here is my code.

```
ods output ParameterEstimates=Pi_Parameters FitStatistics=Pi_Summary PredictedValues=Pi_Fitted;
proc glm data=Train_Pi;
class Area Fo5 Tye M0 M1 M2 M3;
model Pi = Dow Area Fo5 Tye M0|HC M1|HC M2|HC M3|HC/solution p ss3 /*tolerance*/;
run;
```

But how to proceed to next step? something like `predict(Model_from_Train_Pi,Test_Pi)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on SAS 9.4 see Jake's answer from this question:

[How to predict probability in logistic regression in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451600/how-to-predict-probability-in-logistic-regression-in-sas)

If not on 9.4, my answer applies for adding the data in to the original data set.

A third option is PROC SCORE - documentation has an example for proc reg that's almost identical to your question:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_score_sect018.htm

Comment: Adding the data to orginal data won't affect the estimates?

Comment: Not if the y/dependent is missing. SAS will exclude those when fitting the model but not in creating estimates. You can easily verify that in the output by looking at the number of observations included.